# RxJava: zip operator thread interrupt error for void observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, cloudinary, reactivex

How the zip operator works in case of two Observable ? For me, it interrupts the other when one is complete. I case of other than void, it waits for each observable to complete, then get back with the results.

The code is

```
   Observable<Void> deleteImageObservable = deleteImage(order.getPrescriptionUrl())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    // deltes order image

    // Deletes order without image
    Observable<Void> deleteOrderObservable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {

        App.getFirebase().child(Constants.Path.ORDERS).child(order.getOrderPath()).removeValue((firebaseError, firebase) -> {
            if (firebaseError != null) {
                // on order delete failed
                Timber.e(firebaseError.toException(), "Order delete failed on id ", order.getOrderId());
                subscriber.onError(firebaseError.toException());
            } else {
                Timber.i("Order deleted, key: %s", order.getOrderPath());
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }

        });

    });

    return Observable.zip(
            deleteImageObservable,
            deleteOrderObservable, (aVoid, aVoid2) -> {
                return aVoid;
            }
    );
```

I am using cloudinary uploader().destroy() to delete image, it returns Void in case of success otherwise exception/error.

It immediately executes the firebase query and on success, interrupts the image delete observable.

Is this the correct behavior ? Or there is a bug in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Zip completes eagerly if one of the input sequences is shorter than the rest. You could instead `merge` sources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's the operator I am looking for. Do you have any suggestion on when to use zip and when to not ?

Comment: zip is useful when you have data to combine row-by-row, but doesn't work as a means of continuation.